# How to get signal strength characteristics of 5G NSA network from CellSignalStrengthLte

Tags: android, kotlin, 5g

As Android developer reference states, TelephonyManager returns CellInfoNr only for 5G SA networks and CellInfoLte for 5G NSA networks. I need to get signal strength information for NSA networks, but can't find the information on how to get it from CellSignalStrengthLte.

5G, as far as I understand, uses Synchronization Signal and Channel State Information instead of Cell-Specific Reference Signal as with 4G, and thus the usual RSRP, RSRQ, and RSSI information are pretty useless with 5G networks.

Have I understood this wrong so that these metrics are actually relevant in NSA network, or how can I get the relevant metrics from the CellSignalStrengthLte object?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could help you call TelephoneManager. You can see below all types.

Use a funciton like this:

```
   fun getNetworkInfo() : Int {
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    if (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
    return networkInfo.subtype
    } else -1
   }
```

than parse the Int to check which type of connection is.

Connection types:

```
    /*
 * When adding a network type to the list below, make sure to add the correct icon to
 * MobileSignalController.mapIconSets() as well as NETWORK_TYPES
 * Do not add negative types.
 */
/** Network type is unknown */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN; // = 0.
/** Current network is GPRS */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS; // = 1.
/** Current network is EDGE */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE; // = 2.
/** Current network is UMTS */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS; // = 3.
/** Current network is CDMA: Either IS95A or IS95B*/
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA; // = 4.
/** Current network is EVDO revision 0*/
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0 = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0; // = 5.
/** Current network is EVDO revision A*/
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A; // = 6.
/** Current network is 1xRTT*/
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_1XRTT; // = 7.
/** Current network is HSDPA */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA; // = 8.
/** Current network is HSUPA */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA; // = 9.
/** Current network is HSPA */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA; // = 10.
/** Current network is iDen */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN; // = 11.
/** Current network is EVDO revision B*/
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B; // = 12.
/** Current network is LTE */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_LTE = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE; // = 13.
/** Current network is eHRPD */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD; // = 14.
/** Current network is HSPA+ */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP; // = 15.
/** Current network is GSM */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_GSM = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM; // = 16.
/** Current network is TD_SCDMA */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_TD_SCDMA =
        TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_TD_SCDMA; // = 17.
/** Current network is IWLAN */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_IWLAN; // = 18.
/** Current network is LTE_CA {@hide} */
@UnsupportedAppUsage
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE_CA; // = 19.
/** Current network is NR(New Radio) 5G. */
public static final int NETWORK_TYPE_NR = TelephonyProtoEnums.NETWORK_TYPE_NR; // 20.
```